# Why does SelectSingleElement work for some queries, but not others?

Tags: xml, selectsinglenode

I have the following snippet of XML (Zimbra SOAP API if anyone cares, but it is not important)

```
<appt id="266" uid="bf177af2-2875-447a-8e74-d9bc8c108611" nextAlarm="1409547300000" d="1380213518000" rev="63" s="0" l="10" xmlns="urn:zimbraMail">
  <inv id="265" seq="3" compNum="0" type="appt">
```

I have an XmlElement which contains this snippet. I have set up a namespace manager etc, as follows

```
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(element.OwnerDocument.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("prefix", "urn:zimbraMail");
```

The following code

```
element.SelectSingleNode("//prefix:" + "appt/@id", ns).Value
```

returns 266 as expected

but I cannot manage to select appt, appt/inv or anything else, except for basically the attributes of appt.  Here are a few of the queries I have tried. Some return null, some return bad format (as I was thrashing around)

```
element.SelectSingleNode("//prefix:" + "appt/inv", ns).Value
element.SelectSingleNode("//prefix:" + "/appt/inv", ns).Value
element.SelectSingleNode("//prefix:" + "/inv", ns).Value
element.SelectSingleNode("//prefix:" + "appt", ns).Value
```

I've also tried not including the prefixes etc. Any help? Part of the issue may be that OwnerDoc is a SOAP envelope, which could be screwing up the namespaces, but then why would the first query work? (Incidentally, the first query works even without using the prefix/namespace logic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to qualify *all* elements, not just the first one. So:

```
//prefix:appt/inv
```

Should be:

```
//prefix:appt/prefix:inv
```

The bad format exception is due to the following, because element names can't start with `/`:

```
//prefix:/appt/inv
//prefix:/inv
```

Comment: that has got to be the stupidest thing I have ever seen. this makes xpath syntax practically worthless to me.

Comment: I ended up just stripping the namespace, it made everything 100x easier.

Comment: Welcome to XML -- very useful but very verbose :)